# IP Address format in HTML

Tags: html, ip

I have an input text for user to input IP Address. Something like this

```
<input type="text" name="ip_address" id="ip_address" />
```

I want the display match IP format, which is 3 spaces and . 3 spaces again something like this

.   .   .

Is there any simple way for me to do that? I did checking for the valid input using Javascript and having no problem with it (below my code), just wonder if i can display the input so that user will input accordingly to IP address format..

`if (!text.match(/^\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}[.]\d{1,3}$/)))`

thanks

Comment: If you just want to show the correct format of thee ip to your user, you may consider using the `placeholder` attribute.

Comment: Your RegExp will match `999.999.999.999`...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct input type for IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306970/correct-input-type-for-ip-address)

Answer (score 0):

You can’t (reasonably) do this with a regular expresssion; as @Passerby comments, your expression would allow any three-digit component. (The unreasonable way is to list down numbers from 0 to 255 four times in the expression.)

So you should split the value to period-separated parts and test each part for being in range.

Comment: Technically you can just list the number two times to create an effective regex: http://regex101.com/r/fU3nU7