# Correct input type for IP Address

Tags: html

What is the best practice for an input field that takes an IP-Address?

ie: Numbers and dots.

I've initially chosen `type='number'`, However, I noticed that as soon as I type a **second** dot `.` followed by the next number, my submit button gets disabled.

*ex: 123.124.4 (boom! button disabled)*

Is the above due to a decimal consideration when it comes to `type=number` ?

```
<input type="number" class="input-box" placeholder="xxx.xxx.xxx.xx" autocomplete="off" />
```

Is there a way out of this without going with `<input type='text'/>` ?

Answer (score 29):

Yes, there is a way to take an IP address via HTML using input without using text type, like a type number. The options would require four input boxes, one for each octet.

Since there is no HTML input type that matches IPv4 address exactly and if you want to stick to a single input field type text is relatively simple with minlength, maxlength, and pattern attributes.

Bare bones HTML:

```
<input type="text" minlength="7" maxlength="15" size="15" pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">
```

**For security reasons** ensure you always validate submitted data server side, not just client side. You can use same regex pattern.

*** Update 3/2/2019 *** Added three IPv6 address regex formats.

Only accepts IPv6 addresses in long form:

```
<input type="text" pattern="^([0-9a-fA-F]{4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{4}$">
```

Accepts long and medium form IPv6 addresses (medium allows leading zeros):

```
<input type="text" pattern="^([0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}:){7}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,4}$">
```

Accepts long and medium form IPv6 addresses (medium without leading zeros):

```
<input type="text" pattern="^(([0-9a-fA-F]{1}|[1-9a-fA-F]{1}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,3}):){7}([0-9a-fA-F]{1}|[1-9a-fA-F]{1}[0-9a-fA-F]{1,3})$">
```

Comment: What regex should be used for IPv6?

Comment: Do `minlength`, `maxlength`, and `size` factor into the IPv6 regexes?

Comment: @Bluu Yes, all my regex examples have built-in minlength, maxlength, and size. So "bare bones HTML" can omit the HTML minlength, maxlength, and size.

Answer (score 8):

In HTML, you can verify input values with a pattern. This way, you can make something with a regular expression as following :

```
<input required pattern="^([0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$">
```

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284147/validating-ipv4-addresses-with-regexp) provides a nice pattern to use.

Comment: The regex supplied allows invalid IPv4 address (like 333.333.333.333). I'll post different answer.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me, using the answer from @ptay. In his answer it was possible to add IP values like 02.09.08.07

```
<input required pattern="^((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">
```

Answer (score 0):

this work for me

```
    9     <mat-form-field class="form-element">
    8     ⎸ <input
    7     ⎸   matInput
    6     ⎸   placeholder="Ip"
    5     ⎸   name="ip"
    4     ⎸   [(ngModel)]="ip"
    3     ⎸   required
    2     ⎸   pattern="^(?:(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.){3}(?:25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)$"
    1     ⎸   [disabled]="data.btnDisabled"
  30      ⎸ />
    1     </mat-form-field>
```