# text field for ip address in laravel

Tags: html, laravel, ip, textfield

what is the correct text field for IP address in HTML, I see some answers here but it did not work for me. Is there any alternative text field.

```
<div class="col-3 col-xs-3 col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 col-xl-3 ">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" class="form-label text-truncate col-9">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="xproject" required pattern="^((\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d{1,2}|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$"> 
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a `text` (without pattern) input field if you want to keep things simple and do the validation on the back-end with Laravel:

```php
$validated = $request->validate([
    'xproject' => 'required|ip'
]);
```

This will accept IP v4 and v6. If you only want ipv4, you can use the `ipv4` rule and conversely `ipv6` for ipv6.

```
'xproject' => 'required|ipv4'
'xproject' => 'required|ipv6'
```

Doc: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-ip

However, if you also want to have a validation on the front-end, there are better solutions with some javascript depending what framework you use or lib. You can also use masks.

However, here is a solution that seems to work:

```html
<input required pattern="^((\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])\.){3}(\d|[1-9]\d|1\d\d|2[0-4]\d|25[0-5])$">
```

The solution comes from an updated answer in 2021 from @Oscar Camargo : https://stackoverflow.com/a/68177118/5282089

Comment: @retorado001 no problem, do not hesitate to mark as resolved^^

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the browser you're testing it on. There is no official `type="ip"` support so you have to resort to `type="text"` with a regex pattern, or create a custom javascript solution that checks the input.

Some solutions are found here:
[Correct input type for IP Address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49306970/correct-input-type-for-ip-address)

However, depending on your requirements you can simplify the design by just allowing *any* input, and make sure to validate it server side. If it's not an ip, the user would receive an error message. In Laravel it would look like [this (link)](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/validation#rule-ip) (use any of the validation rules `ip`, `ipv4` or `ipv6`) :

```php
// SomeController.php
public function someAction(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'ip' => 'required|ip',
    ];
}
```